# MongoDB update operation performance

Tags: mongodb, performance, nosql

The update query performance varies significantly when the field values are set to the same value. MongoDB version: 4.2.6

**Run 1:**

no. of documents: 1 million

time taken to update 1M documents: 13m31.227s

```
db.test.find().forEach(function(doc){db.test.update({_id:doc._id}, {$set:{counter: 400}})})
```

**Run 2:**

no. of documents: 1 million

time taken to update 1M documents: 7m41.080s

```
db.test.find().forEach(function(doc){db.test.update({_id:doc._id}, {$set:{counter: 400}})})
```

**Run 3: **After mongod restart and cleaning buff/cache manually****

no. of documents: 1 million

time taken to update 1M documents: 7m41.080s

```
db.test.find().forEach(function(doc){db.test.update({_id:doc._id}, {$set:{counter: 400}})})
```

**Run 4: **Setting counter to new value****

no. of documents: 1 million

time taken to update 1M documents: 13m44.284s

```
db.test.find().forEach(function(doc){db.test.update({_id:doc._id}, {$set:{counter: 500}})})
```

**Run 5:**

no. of documents: 1 million

time taken to update 1M documents: 7m42.356s

```
db.test.find().forEach(function(doc){db.test.update({_id:doc._id}, {$set:{counter: 500}})})
```

Does mongodb perform additional checks while setting the value of a field? What can cause such performance difference for same update operation?

Comment: can you paste plan cache and query plans of each run as well?  you can use `db.collection.explain()`  to get query plan and `db.collection.getPlanCache()` to get plan cache

Comment: but what is clear, for the first time when you run the query mongodb tries to make the query plan and cache it, so each time you change it , it takes extra time to do so.

Comment: since the query pattern is same for all of the queries, mongodb will prepare plan for first query and cache it for n number of subsequent calls. Taking ~6mins for selecting plan is very unlikely. Please note that both after update operations take same time even after server restart. Restarting server cause plan cache to flush but it didn't affect the performance - run 2 & run 3

Comment: Why do you not simply use `db.test.updateMany({}, {$set:{counter: 400}})`?

Answer (score 0):

when you run a query for the very first time , MongoDB (or any other DBMS) make a query plan for it and cache it. so next time you run the same query, MongoDB uses that query plan ( unless it has been cleared from cache).

Also If you do any changes to the query ( even if it is the same pattern ( using your word) still it is a new query with no cached query plan , so MongoDB tries to make the query plan and cache it.
to test this you can run your query then clear the cache using :

```
db.colllction_name.getPlanCache().clear()
```

and run your query again , you will see that again It's gonna take more time to run that query ( probably same as the first run)

also each time you run any query use `explain("executionStats")` and compare the stats